# Using a different DNS with OpenVPN Connect on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, vpn, openvpn

I'm using OpenVPN Connect on Windows 10. First, I do not have access to any of the server settings for the VPN configuration. I couldn't find how to configure openvpn connect on the client side to not auto-add routes and DNS, so I did it manually via the "route" command post-connect.

The reason I want to do this is because I need to use my work vpn to connect to certain resources, but it is slow and in another country, so it is tedious to have it on when browsing the web. My goal is to only use the VPN to access the resources that need it.

I'm having trouble getting Windows to use my own DNS though. When I connect to the VPN, I'm unable to connect to port 53 on my router. Other ports work fine though (i.e. 80 or pinging). Likewise, nslookup will fail due to not being able to connect to the router's DNS. Port 53 is fine when disconnecting from the VPN. This is also the case for other public DNS, like 8.8.8.8.

I'm not really sure how to troubleshoot it further.. I assume the routes are fine since ping can reach it... there are no "Deny" firewall rules either. I'm not sure by what mechanism openvpn connect is disabling the non-VPN DNS connections.

Comment: I do not have access to any of the server settings for the VPN configuration.  <-- I have done lots of VPN. You need the server side to connect.

Comment: There's `pull-filter` in openvpn